Emacs M-x eglot unable to connect to solargraph
I figured I'd join the modern dev world and check out Eglot for the first time in Emacs 29.3.  When I enter M-x eglot on a Ruby file, I receive the error:
eglot--error: [eglot] `solargraph' not found in PATH, but can't form an interactive prompt for to fix (solargraph socket --port :autoport)!

Poking around, it appears I may need to set up either an independent Ruby/Rails app from which to serve solargraph (and solargraph-rails), or maybe install the gems in my current app and run its server when using emacs.  And, maybe change the port for the emacs variable eglot-server-programs to match the Rails dev-mode standard 3000.
Is any of that correct?
I've made an earnest attempt to dig around on the web to suss before posting this question, and it's just not clear what's required to get Eglot working for Ruby.

you can try to install solargraph.
gem install solargraph

and make sure solargraph in PATH.
$ ll /home/yourname/XDG_DATA_HOME/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin
total 64K
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 554 Jul 18 15:14 htmldiff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 551 Jul 18 15:14 kramdown
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 548 Jul 18 15:14 ldiff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 551 Jul 18 15:13 nokogiri
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 527 Jul 18 15:13 racc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 521 Jul 18 15:14 rbs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 599 Jul 18 15:13 reverse_markdown
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 545 Jul 18 15:13 rubocop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 547 Jul 18 15:13 ruby-parse
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 551 Jul 18 15:13 ruby-rewrite
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 563 Jul 18 15:18 solargraph          # here
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 527 Jul 18 15:13 thor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 527 Jul 18 15:13 tilt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 527 Jul 18 15:13 yard
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 531 Jul 18 15:13 yardoc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yourname yourgroup 525 Jul 18 15:13 yri

$ export PATH="$HOME/XDG_DATA_HOME/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin:$PATH"         # you can write to .bashrc or .zshrc

